# WinFrame App C# game design: Moving pictureboxes left and right

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

I would like my pictureboxes to move left and right, so far they're only moving right and disappearing when they reach the edge. In the code there are 3 enemies, they can all move to the right, how can I make these move left when they hit "the wall"? The Player can move both directions.

```
{
Random _random;


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _random = new Random();
}

private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Size s = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
    this.ClientSize = s; 
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}

private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            Player.Left -= 20;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            Player.Left += 20;
        }

    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int z = _random.Next(0, 10);
    int x = _random.Next(0, 20);
    int y = _random.Next(0, 30);
    LargeEnemy.Left += z;
    MediumEnemy.Left += x;
    SmallEnemy.Left += y;

}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, it works with a picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code I made this, first make 3 global bools: `bool LargeGoLeft = true, MediumGoLeft = true, SmallGoLeft = true;`
Then put the code in your timer like so:

```
    bool moveLeft = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if((pictureBox1.Left + pictureBox1.Width) >= this.Width)
        {
            moveLeft = true;
        }
        if(pictureBox1.Left < 0)
        {
            moveLeft = false;
        }
        if(moveLeft)
        {
            pictureBox1.Left -= 15;
        }
        if (!moveLeft)
        {
            pictureBox1.Left += 15;
        }
    }
```

This is the version I was able test and it works perfectly with a picturebox

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so far it didn't work out for me.

This part:
if ((LargeEnemy.Left + LargeEnemy.Width) >= MainWindow.Width)
            {
                LargeGoLeft = false;
            }

Gives me the following error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'control.width'

Comment: Your enemies do not have a width? if else just leave the + width part and do + 50 or so (if you know the width just enter it)

Comment: It's a step in the right direction. I just have to figure out why they all go left, when only one of the enemies hit the wall, they have different speed and sizes.

Comment: Use 3 booleans instead of the 1

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it. This has helped me a lot. I will keep all this in mind the next time I would like to move pictureboxes!